# XPATH selecting node with attribute and text

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Given (no comments about the XML naming necessary):

```
<config>
  <unit>
    <var name='model'>3100</var>
    <var name='type'>production</var>
  </unit>
<unit>
    <var name='model'>0100</var>
    <var name='type'>test</var>
  </unit>
</config>
```

How can I construct an XPATH to select the node with the attribute "model" and the text 3100 using Ruby Nokogiri

I'm trying:

```
//var[@name='model' and text()='3100']
```

but getting "invalid predicate".  Obviously that's just the XPATH with the Nokogiri calls omitted.  I don't seem to be having any problems with the Nokogiri usage, so my request is just about fixing the XPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works with nokogiri 1.5, Are you using a very old version?

Comment: Doh!  There was a stray parenthesis in my predicate that I didn't notice.  Thanks for the help.