# Writing Xpath with attribute and text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I'm a newbie to Selenium and I need to be able to xpath the following element with attribute and text.

I am using

```
//*[text()='Over Due']
```

but I need it with attribute also to narrow it down to the single element.

```
<div style="padding-right: 10px;"><mat-icon role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate timer-gray material-icons mat-icon-no-color" style="vertical-align: bottom;" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font"> av_timer </mat-icon> Over Due </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPATH selecting node with attribute and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618880/xpath-selecting-node-with-attribute-and-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute with your existing XPath like

```
//*[text()='Over Due' and @attribute='']
```

OR with child expression also

```
//div[text()='Over Due' and *[text()='some text']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath-1.0 expression which includes the text node and part of the attributes:

```
//div[normalize-space(text())='Over Due' and contains(@style,'padding-right: 10px;') and contains(mat-icon/@class,'mat-icon')]
```

If this does not suffice, add further  `contains(...)`  expressions.